# What is differential between useFactory and useValues?

Tags: jestjs, mocking, nestjs

What is differential between `useFactory` and `useValues` who using for mock my module in `createTestingModule` on **NestJS**

I read [Testing | NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing) and I read the article but found no explanation about the difference or when to use either mode.

Comment: It depends on what's your mock object looks like. I guess there's no much to say besides that with `useFactory` you can inject things, while with `useValue` you can't

Answer (score 0):

Really, nothing more than [`useFactory`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory) accepts a function and *could* be used to inject values based on the current module while [`useValue`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#value-providers-usevalue) is a direct value. There's really not much more to it than that. They're just [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers)